# Connecting SQL running on Vagrant machine through remote host?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, portforwarding, emma

I am trying to connect Emma to MySQL running on Vagrant Machine with nginx from a remote location. The server (host) has a static ip that can be accessed through internet. It also has its own running MySQL instance that I can connect to. However I want to connect to Vagrant's MySQL from a remote location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to expose the port of the MySQL server's running on Vagrant to the public internet. There are a number of ways, but the simplest should be [configuring Vagrant with port forwarding](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html).

Since you already have another MySQL server running on the host, you would need to forward on another (free) port than the default, for example `6306`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 6306
end
```

You would also need to explicitly specify that port in the connection url in Emma.

Comment: A little new to all this so thank you. Worked like a charm !